# Suggestions for use case pattern using truecrypt to encrypt user folders in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I have a new windows 8.1 notebook computer and I want to use truecrypt with it to make all of my data secure. My computer has 2 different drives. My first idea was to encrypt all of my drives. However, I ran into a problem when trying to encrypt my system partition. I get the message "Your system drive has a GUID partition table (GPT). Currently, only devices with a MBR partition table are supported."

I know it might be possible to make an image of my C: drive and re-install windows on it using MBR, but I thought that I would sidestep that task and simply encrypt my other drive and store all of my user data on it and install all non essential programs on it.

So, I encrypted my D: drive and I can mount it in truecrypt and assign it to say Z: I opened up my user folder and for each sub folder in there, I went to its properties and changed its location to reside on my Z: drive. So my Documents reside at Z:\Users\John\Documents my Desktop resides at Z:\Users\John\Desktop etc.

This all works, but I get the issue that when I first log in, my Z: drive is no yet mounted and so I get dialog boxes saying Z:\Users\John\Desktop is unavailable. This makes perfect sense to me, but it is very annoying as I get a bunch of dialog boxes when I first log in, and my desktop is not available at login, my taskbar is blank so none of my pinned programs are available etc. Even after I mount my Z drive, my desktop and taskbar remain blank.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to the best pattern to use truecrypt? Is there a way I can force it to auto mount my Z: drive before I log in? Am I doing a foolhardy thing trying to locate my user folders to my Z: drive? Is there a more elegant way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Any insight is appreciated.

Thank You
John Lawrie

Version Information

My PC Info page just says windows 8.1

Help | About Windows says

Microsoft Windows
Version 6.3 (Build 9600)

Clicking on This PC and selecting properties says Windows edition is Windows 8.1

Comment: What version of Windows 8.1?